# What should be returned from Spring @Service when User was not found?

Tags: spring, service, null, option-type

As the title says, I have some repository like:

```
public UserRepository{
    public Optional<User> findByUsername(String username){..logic..}
}
```

and Service:

```
public UserService {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public Optional<User> findByUsername(String username){ ..calling repository.. }
}
```

And in my @Controller class I want to obtain User instance from the UserService

But I have no idea what should be returned from @Service - Optional and check if it isPresent() inside controller, or just simply null? I am confused..

I am trying to move so many logic into @Service layer as I can, so checking optional may seem not good idea.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally what you should do is throw an Exception. This is the best practice to do so. However you can also stick with null if you want but an exception clearly states what is the problem and is very maintainable and dubuggable at later stages.

you might like to do something like this

```
findByUsername(String username){

  // find user
 if(user !=null){
  return User
 }
 else 
   throw new UserNotFoundException();


}
```

Follow this link for how to create custom exceptions.
http://techekiras.blogspot.in/2015/02/how-to-create-custom-exception-in-java.html

and this for how to handle these
http://www.ekiras.com/2015/02/how-to-create-nested-custom-exceptions-in-java.html

Catch these exceptions on your controller to take further actions.

Comment: you pasted 2 the same links ;) I thought about throwing and exception, how I did in my RESTful apps, but I have heard that reducing exceptions to minimum is good practice. So If there is possibility to avoid one, then it should be. 
From which layer would you throw the exception? I think it should be performed on Service layer to avoid pushing "buissnes logic" into controllers, what do you think?

Comment: well exceptions are a heavy task since it contains the full stacktrace, also the ideally all exceptions should be caught in services, but at last it depends on you, what suites your project architecture. I choose exceptions over returning null values, since you always know whats happening around, Suppose you make a update method which return true or false depending on if row is updated or not. if the user is not found you can just throw exception and these can be reused in many places.

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8 there is a new possibility. To make the service to return an [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html). It is a good way to make explicit in the signature that it may return a null. You will be forced to check if it is Null but can be very helpfull to [avoid the famous NullPointerException](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java8-optional-2175753.html)

```
import java.util.Optional;

[...]

public Optional<User> getUser(String userName){

     User user = userDAO.getByUsername(username);
     return Optional.of(user);
}
```